# How to create loop python tkinter arc shape

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I draw shapes in tkinter and code is like this ->

```
myCanvas.create_arc(30, 290, -10, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
myCanvas.create_arc(40, 290, 0, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
myCanvas.create_arc(50, 290, 10, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)  
myCanvas.create_arc(60, 290, 20, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)      
myCanvas.create_arc(70, 290, 30, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(80, 290, 40, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(90, 290, 50, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(100, 290, 60, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(110, 290, 70, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(120, 290, 80, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)  
myCanvas.create_arc(130, 290, 90, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(140, 290, 100, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(150, 290, 110, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2) 
myCanvas.create_arc(160, 290, 120, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)   
myCanvas.create_arc(170, 290, 130, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)    
myCanvas.create_arc(180, 290, 140, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)   
myCanvas.create_arc(190, 290, 150, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
myCanvas.create_arc(200, 290, 160, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
myCanvas.create_arc(210, 290, 170, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
myCanvas.create_arc(220, 290, 180, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
myCanvas.create_arc(230, 290, 190, 160, start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
```

I want to make it easy and want to loop so then I wrote this code ->

```
y1 = 290
y2 = 160
for k in range(30, 240, 10):
    x1 = k
    # print(x1)
    for j in range(-10, 200, 10):
            x2 = j
            # print (x2)
            myCanvas.create_arc(x1, y1, x2, y2,start = 160, extent = -70, style = ARC, outline = 'green', width = 2)
```

But the final result is different . What is wrong with my loop code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 for loops. Try adding `print(x1, x2)` just before your `.create_arc(...)`. For each iteration of the outer for loop, the inner one runs 21 times.

Your for loop fixed:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

y1 = 290
y2 = 160
for x1 in range(30, 240, 10):
    x2 = x1 - 40
    canvas.create_arc(x1, y1, x2, y2, start=160, extent=-70, outline="green", width=2)

root.mainloop()
```